# Rails 4.1 unable to autoload namespaced class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autoloader

I've done an helper for nested resource's urls

```
# app/urls/url.rb
module Url; end
```

Then

```
# app/urls/base.rb
module Url
  class Base
    # common code
  end
end
```

When I try to inherit from `Url::Base`, a `LoadError` arise:

```
Unable to autoload constant Base, expected xxx/app/urls/base.rb to define it
```

I've debugged it a little, the file is correctly sourced and the class loaded, but the check is bugged. The error seems to born in `ActiveSupport::Dependencies#const_missing`, when it pass `Object` as `from_mod` (<- this the variable that is expected to include the constant), instead of `Url`.
Try this:

```
Url::Base # Raise LoadError
Url::Base # Works!
```

I can't still understand why `const_missing` trigger on `Object` instead of `Url`... Some help? What I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

Ok, with more digging, I've understand what's going on. Rails search for a file's path like `namespace/class_name.rb` in `PATH`; if this file doesn't exists, it try to load the constant in the parent's module (or class), and that's why it will recurse with `form_model = Object`.

Comment: How do you load what is in 'app/urls'? Also: are you sure that is th exact error? Because your module is singular, yet the folder is plural.

Comment: If I recall it correctly, since Rails 3 every folder under 'app/' is included in PATH, so yes, it's correct. You can also see that the correct file is sourced in the exception's message, and that's why if you call it a second time, it works

Comment: I'm stuck with the same error. Even better, if I move the class (your `urls` class for example) to `lib` folder, all works :(

Comment: @AndréHerculano In my case, the error was to use "urls" intead of "url" in the path. It must reflect the namespace, so if your class' full name is "Example::Test", its path must be "app/example/test.rb". Is this a little more clear? :)

Comment: If you don't want to move things under app/lib (as maybe lib contains misc classes) you can create a directory such as app/namespaced/ and nest everything under there - eg. app/namespaced/url/base.rb (I think you will need to use 'url' in the directory name rather than 'urls' or the autoloader won't work).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with more digging, I've understand what's going on. Rails search for a file's path like `namespace/class_name.rb` in `PATH`; if this file doesn't exists, it try to load the constant in the parent's module (or class), and that's why it will recurse with `form_model = Object`.